# Using GoPro Studio to edit non-GoPro videos

Tags: video, mp4, software, gopro

I'm trying to use GoPro Studio to create a video that includes GoPro video as well as HD video from an iPhone.  GoPro Studio was not able to deal with the .MOV file from the iPhone (the audio was corrupted).

I then used `avconv` to convert the iPhone video to an .MP4 format file.  The audio now works properly, but GoPro Studio will not let me extract clips from it.  Specifically, the "mark in" and "mark out" buttons are disabled.

Is there a way to convert iPhone videos into a format that's fully editable (and clippable) by GoPro Studio?  Or, is GoPro Studio (a free app) detecting the original source of the video, and only supporting videos from supported sources?

For additional info, here is the format of my converted file:

```
avprobe version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
built on Aug 10 2014 18:16:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0247.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2014-09-01 23:25:15
    date            : 2014-09-01T19:25:15-0400
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
  Duration: 00:05:48.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6423 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 6243 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.98 tbr, 782775.00 tbn, 59.96 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-01 23:25:15
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 175 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-01 23:25:15
# avprobe output
```